# Importing multiple xml files with T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How can I insert multiple xml files into a SQL Server table?

I have managed to get only 1 named file with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE #ZSK70 (Name varchar(25) , Value varchar(30),);

INSERT INTO #ZSK70 (Name, Value) 
SELECT X.variable.query('Name').value('.', 'varchar(25)'),
       X.variable.query('Value').value('.', 'varchar(30)')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'path+filename.xml',

     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
     ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('CollectedData/variable') AS X(variable);
```

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Comment: xml files have the same structure?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969866/bulk-insert-multiple-xml-files-with-ssis-2008

Comment: the exact same structure. only the name changes but with the same lenght.

Comment: i'm working with sql server 2005

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956409/ssis-reading-multiple-xml-files-from-folder